# Error when running migrate and seed together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been running

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`

in development.  This has been working fine...up until today.  Multiple people on my team are seeing this with a specific application.  Now we get error when seeding the database.  The last migration renames a column (this migration has been in place for two months).  The rake task crashes when the `seed` step fires (the seed data has been changed to use the next column name).

This works fine

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

I've gone back and checked older commits in my `master` and they're also breaking.  It's odd that this just started happening on code that has been known to work.

Rails 5.0.2, Ruby 2.3.4, Rake 12.0.0

Comment: `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate && rake db:seed` should work fine too.

Comment: Yep, that works as expected.  I've been trying avoid that since it causes the rake to load the environment 4 times.

Comment: This should work - Sounds like you're best of posting an issue on the Rails-repository on Github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tracked it down.  It turns out an earlier migration had some code that talked to the `User` class and performed some data transformations.  By referencing `User` in a migration, Rails loaded the attribute definitions for the model.  Then another migration came along and changed a column name.  When we later use `User` in a seed file, it's still holding the original attribute definition and crashes.

That explains why running `rake db:seed` separately worked.  Rails had an opportunity to restart the environment and read the attribute definitions again.

Our final solution was to delete the old data transformation since it's already been applied to prod.  It's only needed for developers who are rebuilding their local development environments (and they have an empty database at that point so there's nothing to transform).

Another solution was to call `User.reset_column_information` after the data transformation ran.  That would wipe out the attribute definition and give the app a clean working state for future migrations (and the seed file).

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with Rails 6.0.3
I have migration that add new columns to existing model, and seed crashes because of this.

Adding

```
ApplicationRecord.reset_column_information
```

at the top of seeds.rb
solved the problem.